# How can I bring my object back to life using deserialization?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I serialized a class object to a file like this:

```
public class GreenhouseControls extends Controller implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7079669536704670179L;
    private long               numOfRings;
    private long               rings;
    private Event              event;
    private Scanner            s;
    private ArrayList<String>  array;
    private ArrayList<String>  array2;
    private ArrayList<String>  array3;
    public  boolean            windowok;
    public  boolean            poweron;
    public  boolean            fans;
    public  boolean            light;
    public  boolean            water;
    public  String             thermostat;
    private String             eventsFile;
    public  int                errorcode;
    private String             dumpFile;

    ......

    public void saveState() {
        try {
            // Serialize data object to a file
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("dump.out"));
            out.writeObject(GreenhouseControls.this);
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
     .....  
}
```

The file exists as shown here:

[image: Package Explorer Image]
 .

Now I want to deserialized the object. This is what I have so far:

```
public class Restore extends Event {

      public Restore(long delayTime, String dumpFile){
          super(delayTime);
          eventsFile = dumpFile;
      } 
      @Override
      public void action() throws ControllerException { 
          try {
              FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(eventsFile);
              ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);  
              GreenhouseControls gc = (GreenhouseControls) ois.readObject(); // Error occurs here 

              ois.close();        
          }catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          } 
      }
      public String toString() {
          return "Restoring system";
      }  
  }
```

Is the above Restore class even close to what I need to do to deserialize my object? 
When I run my program I am getting WriteAbortedException and NotSerializableException.

Here are the exceptions:

```
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.Scanner
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at greenhouse.GreenhouseControls$Restore.action(GreenhouseControls.java:374)
    at other.Controller.run(Controller.java:39)
    at greenhouse.GreenhouseControls.main(GreenhouseControls.java:530)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.Scanner
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at greenhouse.GreenhouseControls.saveState(GreenhouseControls.java:487)
    at other.Controller.run(Controller.java:43)
    at greenhouse.GreenhouseControls.main(GreenhouseControls.java:524)
```

Here is my Event class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import greenhouse.GreenhouseControls.ControllerException;

public abstract class Event implements Serializable{
  private long eventTime;
  protected final long delayTime;


  public Event(long delayTime) {
      this.delayTime = delayTime;
      start();
  }

  public void start() { // Allows restarting
    eventTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + delayTime;
  }

  public boolean ready() {
    return System.currentTimeMillis() >= eventTime;
  }

  public abstract void action() throws ControllerException;
 }
```

Comment: can u post the code for GreenhouseControls?

Comment: I would but it's a huge file.

Comment: as in a general overview of the class is fine, don't need to post the specific method code, but just class/method declarations

Comment: You haven's posted the code for the class you're serializing. From the errors you might have a field that is not serializable. But impossible to know without the code or at least the full error.

Comment: @vanza - See edit above for exceptions printed to console and variables used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't serialize a `Scanner.` Or any kind of input or output stream, reader, writer, socket, connection, ... Make the scanner transient. Better still make it a local variable in whatever methods use it. You're unlikely to be using the same `Scanner` for the life of the class, and if you are, I suggest you're doing something wrong.

Comment: If I make it a local variable but it's in a method that is inside of GreenhouseControls will that be okay? Or do I have to remove the scanner completely outside of GreenhouseControls in order for GreenhouseControls to be serializable?

Comment: If it is a local variable declared inside a method then you don't have  to remove it from there. It will be OKAY

Comment: @LooMeenin What part of 'Better still make it a local variable in whatever methods use it' didn't you understand?

Comment: @EJP - Apparently all of it. Not sure how I missed that. I started out pretty dumb but I think it's gotten a lot worse since I started programming!

Answer (score 1):

Some points to remember before serialization,

1. If the class is marked as `Serializable,` then all the variables contained inside the class should be `Serializable` too.
2. If class contains some objects that can not be serialized then add `transient` keyword against them.

In your case, you should declare `Scanner` variable as `transient`

```
private transient Scanner s;
```

Secondly, is your class `Event` serializable? i.e. does it implements `Serializable` or not if it is your own custom class.

Comment: Yes, my Event class implements Serializable and it doesn't include anything that can't be serialized. See edit above to view Event class.